# Error sudoing commands

Tags: sudo

Every time I try to sudo some command (e.g. sudo vi /etc/hosts), I receive the following error

```
-bash: /tmp/OETEX: No such file or directory
```

Any command I try to sudo, gives the same error

Can someone give me an hint to understand what's wrong?

If I create a `/tmp/OETEX` file I receive a permission denied error

Also if I just type sudo, I receive the usual message: -bash: /tmp/OETEX: No such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output of `type sudo`?

Comment: Can you also include the exact command you were *trying* to run?

Comment: Just try rebooting, since the error is coming from the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: I've rebooted several times, without changes